# Asking users how they heard about us

Tags: forms, user-behavior, user-expectation, users, surveys

When is the best time to ask the user the question, "How did you hear about us?"

We haven't fully decided how to best phrase this question, but how do you bring this up contextually to a user?

We'd like to expose this question to everyone, if possible, and not just those who try to reach out to us through the Contact form.

Comment: Let's be goal-oriented, what do you aim for by asking this question? Then we can discuss whether the current situation is gonna match your goal and if not, how and when will

Comment: Honestly? Don't. Use analytics to see where they've come from, because you know those are accurate. But even if there is a good opportunity to ask the question of the user, how can you ever be sure they've not just picked something at random to get the question to go away? (I know I do that). And also - why do you even need to know?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Commonly we get the data of how the users heard our products or where/which channel they came from, aiming at distinguishing the most efficient channel to attract and accumulate new users as well as which channel brings high ROI users. Then we may put in more effort in those channels. But if it's yet the very beginning of my new product, the results are likely of less conclusive sense because of a smaller user amount and a short observation period. Just want to be more accurate :)

Comment: Back to the topic, sure that users are lazy and tend to "just picked something at random to get the question to go away". Such situation happens more often while users' tasks are interrupted. So here are my opinions: 1. Put the question markedly on the main page/screen of your product--conspicuous and not to be neglected. 2. Don't make it a pop-up window or something that will interrupt users' paths to get them annoyed--don't have to do it right now. eg: a nice designed suspending module at the bottom of your home page that will disappear after being given an answer and saying thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to do it. You can get this information from analytics tools. You can set goals or tag each link that use to bring new customers.

Just for users that call to your company, you can give some training for the people that answer the phone and they can find the best moment to ask this for the customer.

And in the last case, you can ask for your developer to find some alternative with cookies.

But if you decide to add the question, please, **never put it before the main conversion happens**, because each extra and unnecessary question will reduce your conversion rate.